# What good learning resources are there for testers who are new to Cucumber?

Tags: tools, learning, test-automation-framework

My team have recently decided to introduce Cucumber for our GUI automated checks. As it happens, we have people in the team who are very experienced with it, so I think we'll be fine, but it's made me curious about what resources are out there for testers without a resident cuke expert.

What good resources are there for testers who are learning Cucumber and test automation for the first time, and may not have much programming experience *yet*?

What about for testers who have experience with other automation tools or know a little bit of programming, but no experience with Cucumber itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's The Secret Ninja Cucumber Scrolls from Gojko - I started off with this

http://cuke4ninja.com/

I'm currently reading The Cucumber Book from Matt Wynne

http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book

The RSpec book might also be useful

and a bunch of resources here
http://mikbe.tk/2011/03/05/learning-cucumber-rspec/
( I have no experience with these so cannot give a recommendation )

Answer (score 1):

I am having fun with Cucumber & Cheese:

https://leanpub.com/cucumber_and_cheese

This would fall under the "good resources are there for testers who are learning Cucumber and test automation for the first time, and may not have much programming experience yet" bucket.  I feel like he is bringing me along at a good pace.